# Asking questions, Past vs Present

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following:

> What is applied mathematics? If you were to summarize it in a few words?
>
> What is applied mathematics? If you are to summarize it in a few words?
>
> What is applied mathematics? If you summarize it in a few words?
>
> What is applied mathematics? [Like] If you were to summarize it in a few words?

Comment: The last part shouldn't be a question.  It should be an imperative statement.

`What is applied mathematics?  Summarize it in a few words.`  You're asking a question and then giving instructions on how to answer it properly.

Comment: You need to set your question in a plausible context. Since I am a language teacher, it is highly unlikely that anyone would ask me to summarize applied mathematics. If they did, they would probably say: "*If you were asked to summarize applied mathematics, what would you say?*" A mathematics teacher on the other hand might be asked: "*If you are asked to summarize applied mathematics in a few words, what do you say?*"

Comment: @Shoe- Thank you, makes sense now. Are my sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: @Noah. The second "sentence" in each case is a dependent clause. A dependent clause cannot stand alone as a complete sentence. I suggest you reword your question to make a complex sentence in each case: Example: *If you were to asked to summarize applied mathematics in a few words, what would you say?* (PS. I don't see a difference between your examples 1 and 4.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

> *What is applied mathematics? Can you summarize it in a few words?*

or,

> *What is applied mathematics? Would you summarize it in a few words?*

or, in the context of an exam question:

> *What is applied mathematics? Summarize it in a few words.*

From the small snippet you've provided, I think either ***can you*** or ***would you*** would read better than ***if you***, ***if you were***, or ***if you are***.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused with the use of 'would' in your second example. Does it relate to a tense? Can we say 'will you'? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: "Will you" works, too.  They're roughly the same.